# create a physical relationship on the tabular model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ssas, tabular

Is it possible to create a physical relationship on the tabular model without using Power BI, Power Pivot, or Analysis Services Table?

To be more precise, can I create a physical relationship with coding (c#, .net core ) and using a package or library?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more what kind of relation you are looking for using C# or asp.net core?

Comment: I want to create relations between two tables of SSAS Database (tabular model) @MdFaridUddinKiron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with this package:  Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular
this code work:

```
using Server server = new();
server.Connect(Configuration["ConnectionString:SSAS"]);
var database = server.Databases.FindByName(Constants.SSASDB);
var fromTable = database.Model.Tables.Find("sourceTableName");
var toTable = database.Model.Tables.Find("destinationTableName");
SingleColumnRelationship columnRelationship = new();
columnRelationship.Name = "relationName";
columnRelationship.FromColumn = fromTable.Columns.Find("sourceColumnName");
columnRelationship.ToColumn = toTable.Columns.Find("destinationColumnName");
columnRelationship.FromCardinality = RelationshipEndCardinality.One;
columnRelationship.ToCardinality = RelationshipEndCardinality.Many;
columnRelationship.CrossFilteringBehavior = CrossFilteringBehavior.OneDirection;
columnRelationship.SecurityFilteringBehavior = SecurityFilteringBehavior.OneDirection;
columnRelationship.RelyOnReferentialIntegrity = false;
columnRelationship.IsActive = true;
database.Model.Relationships.Add(columnRelationship);
database.Model.SaveChanges();
```